# Unable to install BeautifulSoup package for Python 3.10 using pip on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.10

I was trying to install BeautifulSoup4 in order to learn web scraping. I was using pip to install bs4 package for Python 3.10 but I am unable to install it. Any help to resolve the below traceback error.
Note: I am using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

```
root@mascot:~# pip install bs4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
        command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
        module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 15, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
        from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 12, in <module>
        from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
    ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 3):

use  **pip install beautifulsoup4** instead of bs4

Comment: Yes tried that already. It gives the same traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Currently **BS4/Beautifulsoup4** is not compatible with Python 3.10 (probably will working in future)

**BS4** Release was in **Sep 8, 2021**
https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#history

**Python** 3.10 realease in: **October 04, 2021**
https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches

I would assume compatibility issues until BS4 will update.

Until then everything should work with 3.9 so I would go with that.